# Sequential async await calls aren't calling properly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to beter understand promises and I dont understand why this doesnt work.

```
async function fooTheBar(a) {
  const b = await Foo(a);
  const c = await Bar(b);
  const d = await fooBar(c);
  return {foooo: d};
}
```

in live practice await bar(b) is running before b is finished being defined by await Foo(a). All of the functions are written as async and they all return data.

Comment: It works. And it executes sequentially. Whatever your "live practice" is, it is caused by something else.

Comment: show us the content of the different asynchronous functions because people can't guess what these functions are doing.

Comment: Your functions probably aren't actually returning promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can work around with below code

```js
function Foo(param){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(param);
  });
}

function Bar(param){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(param);
  });
}

function fooBar (param){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(param);
  });
}

async function fooTheBar(a) {
  const b = await Foo(a);
  const c = await Bar(b);
  const d = await fooBar(c);
  return {foooo: d};
}

fooTheBar("foo").then((resp)=>{  console.log(resp)})
```